# Boundedness of solution $u$ with PDE $-\Delta u + u = f$

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes

I want to get the boundedness of (weak) solution $u$ to the following elliptic PDE with Robin boundary condition:
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
   \begin{aligned}
   - \Delta u + u & = f   \qquad  in~ \Omega, \\
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} + \gamma u & = g  \qquad  on~\Gamma,
   \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

Assumptions:

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d~(d=2,3)$ is an open bounded set
with Lipschitz continuous boundary $\Gamma$.

the Robin coefficient $\gamma \in L^2(\Gamma)$ is bounded, i.e, $0 < c_{min} \leq \gamma \leq c_{max} < \infty$

$g \in H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$, $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

If the equation was $-\Delta u = f$, I might try proceeding with Maximum/Minimum Principle. But in this case I got stuck.

I tried estimating $u_{H^1(\Omega)}$, but then realized boundedness of $u_{H^1(\Omega)}$ does not impliy boundedness of $u$ itself.

Any hints will be helpful. Thank you.